# Can we stop animate in TGIFImage delphi component?

Tags: image, delphi, image-processing, delphi-7, vcl

Sometimes i want to run gif image with animate once or twice,,and stop it,, is there possible to do that?

Comment: Which component are you using for GIF image support ? There was not any *built-in* class in Delphi 7 as far as I remember.

Comment: @TLama Everyone used the gifimage library that was was later absorbed by the borg

Comment: I use TGIFImage component from http://melander.dk/delphi/gifimage/,,,

Answer (score 3):

The animation is controlled by the [`Animate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg.TGIFImage.Animate) property of the `TGIFImage` control. Set it to `True` to animate, and set it to `False` to stop the animation.

There is also the [`AnimateLoop`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg.TGIFImage.AnimateLoop) property. If that is `True` then the animation loops endlessly. Otherwise it runs once and then stops. If you want to run the animation once then set `AnimateLoop` to `False` and then set `Animate` to `True`.

Finally you have the [`OnLoop`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg.TGIFImage.OnLoop) event. That fires each time a looped animation loops back to the start. So, if you want to show an animation twice or more then you need to set `AnimateLoop` to `True` and then count the loops in an `OnLoop` handler.

Comment: how to use animate property in [TGIFImage](http://melander.dk/delphi/gifimage/) component? i can't find it.

Comment: Since you have Delphi 7, I assume you are using [those maintained by Finn Tolderlund](http://www.tolderlund.eu/delphi/), don't you ? If so, which one of them are you using ? The [latest available one](http://www.tolderlund.eu/delphi/gifimaged2010b.zip) has `Animate` property.

Comment: @TLama The one I'm looking at is the one I used back in D6 times. It has `Animate` and `OnLoop`. I think it's missing `AnimateLoop`. All that means is that you'll need to use `OnLoop` to implement `AnimateLoop=False` functionality. It's the Finn Tolderlund code, version 2.2, dated 2001.07.23.