# Stop GIF after one execution in Delphi

Tags: loops, delphi, gif

I've a problem with GIFs in my Delphi project (I'm using Delphi 10.4 Sydney). I'm not able to stop GIF after one execution.
I don't want to loop endlessly.

I've tried this:

```
frameGif := (Image1.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage);
frameGif.AnimateLoop := false;
frameGif.Animate := true;
```

GIF doesn't stop after one execution.

I've found these solutions:

[Can we stop animate in TGIFImage delphi component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923603/can-we-stop-animate-in-tgifimage-delphi-component)

[TGIFImage with animated GIF - events are not working - how to detect animation progress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47117744/tgifimage-with-animated-gif-events-are-not-working-how-to-detect-animation-p)

Is TGIFRenderer approach still only way?

How can I use OnLoop event (if I must) when I create GIFs programmatically during program execution?

Best regards....

Comment: If you create the GIFs programmatically then set number of times to be played to 1 instead of 0 (infinite). Some places call this the repeat count but that term is confusing as it suggests setting it to zero would stop looping the animation after the initial animation.

Comment: Thank you Brian.
When I said that I created GIFs programmatically I actually meant that I create "holders" for GIFs (TImage). But your answer pushes me in the direction that is best workaround that I have till now. I've created GIF files with loop information inside them set to one.

I'm now thinking about moving from Delphi 10.4 to Delphi 11 in hope that these functionalities are implemented now. I'll spend little more time on this.

Thanks...